# Format hour in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, nsdateformatter

I am developing an app in Objective C and I have a String like this "10001100" and I want it to look like this "10:00-11:00"
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `NSString * s = @"10001100"; s = @"10:00-11:00";`

Comment: what is this? @JoshCaswell

Comment: That's the code for the string you said you wanted.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's not correct. Your code has a reference pointing to a string instance @"100011000" and makes a reference pointing to string instance @"10:00-11:00" out of it. :-]

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, unless it's a mutable string, I'm afraid that's the best I can do.

Comment: What the previous commentors are trying to hint at is the SO way is you need to show you've made some effort and should show the code you've tried and failed. You have a string (`NSString`). Does that class provide substring operations? Concatenation? Formatting? If when you've got some code you can't get it to work you can ask another question or edit this one (though it will likely be closed soon so the latter option goes).

Comment: Even more than "code I tried" in this case, though, an actual problem statement is necessary. Where are you getting the original string? Are there others like it? What are the parameters of the format: is there a possible string "1000300", or will it be "10000300", or will it be "10001500"? How about "5001000", "15300945", and "00000000"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest solution is to create a method to return a new formatting string based on your requiremnts:

```
NSString* source = @"11001200"; //test length = 6
NSString* hh1 = [source substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
NSString* mm1 = [source substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];

NSString* hh2 = [source substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 2)];
NSString* mm2 = [source substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)];

NSString* results =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@-%@:%@",hh1,mm1,hh2,mm2];
```

Comment: Thanks, this really solved my problem! @Idali

Comment: What's the point of initially assigning the empty string to `results`?

Comment: @rmaddy just because the code is a complete body of a method

Comment: Huh? Why don't you initialize `results` like all of the other variables?

Comment: because the code is not meant to be used as is, but inside a method with result as outputString, meanwhile results could be initialized with default value if the sourceString is not as expected (length =8 ).

Comment: @Idali In such a case `result` should have `nil` (aka "No string") instead of `@""`(aka empty string).

Comment: I edited my answer to focus only on the mean question.